# Delay Process exit

Tags: c#, winapi

I would like to delay the process exit.
When relaying on:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;
```

**Windows limits your actions to two seconds**, then it will terminate the process.

I would like to increase this time. What i found so far is [ICLRPolicyManager::SetTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164398(v=vs.90).aspx), but this requires an external native process to host the CLR code. Maybe I can interop the management interface into CLR code?..

*Sidenote:* Application.Exit, etc will not do the Job, since it it bound to WPF as other solutions are bound to a concrete technology. I need to cover console, services, and UI applications with my solution.

Comment: How does this work? If the user doesnt do anything in your application for 2 seconds it closes? Why dont you handle it all yourself and use timers?

Comment: *Delay process exit* looks like a solution to some problem. And delaying process is wrong solution. Process should still run for as long as you need it. If you trying to overcome windows shutdown, then please, don't do it, follow rules.

Comment: @Sinatr No, I am not trying to delay Windows shutdown. This is about gracefull cleaining on a process exit call. So yes, I need to increase the exit time. For most specific tenologies (WPF, Forms, Services) there is a way to acive this. I am looking for a generic solution.

Comment: `ICLRPolicyManager::SetTimeout` won't help you, it's the OS that is terminating the process (if we're talking about termination). Short answer: no, you cannot delay process termination. Slightly longer: as you are aware, you can delay *closing* the app depending on the technology (unless it's a console app). You might be able to use these two seconds to launch an external app to do certain cleanup actions, although I am not sure what your actual use cases are (are you writing some sort of a library?) given your "generic" requirements.

Comment: SetTimeout will actually help, but I need to wrap everything with a native host - which is quite clumpsy. Yes I am creating a sort of library - delaying the close would do the job, if it was possible in a generic way. Hmm.. is there a way to wrap soemthing around a console app to get a "Close/Exit" like Event?...

Comment: So you need time to clean. Legit way of doing so is to use [destructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e.aspx) (see also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx) version of same msdn article, lol at microsoft, and some [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx)). They will be guarantily called by GC.

Comment: No. I don't need a destructor. I don't want to dive into a discussion about memory management, gc, etc in clr. I am also not looking for an advice or workaround. I am looking for exactly what I asked for. A way to extend the Process Timeout or a close-like event.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you need to extend the process exit time - if your process takes so long to shut down cleanly, maybe you could look into why that is. As the documentation says, the event handler should be performing termination activities, such as closing files, etc. That said, the 2 second timeout is the time for all `ProcessExit` event handlers I think? 2 seconds is quite a long time in computing, these days.

Comment: In most cases it's sufficient, but not in every case. As said, I will not discuss the approach. I'm really looking for a technical solution not for a design advice :)

Comment: I don't understand why SetTimeout() is not found in mscoree.dll. I found [these](https://github.com/AArnott/pinvoke/blob/master/src/MSCorEE/MSCorEE.cs) wrappers for mscoree.dll exported functions, but SetTimeout() is missing. I also check with DependencyWalker, and SetTimeout() is not there.

Comment: Did y solve this ?